# Filter an object with key and value pair with an array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

I have an schema of data as

```
let data = [{
    "Count": {
        "Grapes": 1,
        "Banana": 6,
    }
}]
```

i need to filter through the object "Count" of data from an array "result"

```
let result = ["Banana"]
```

and get an output as

```
let output = {"Banana": 6}
```

How will i achieve this using javascript
I have tried

```
let output = data[0]["Count"].filter( i => result.includes( data[0]["Count"] ));
```

Comment: I suggest checking out the MDN doc on [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and similar methods (map, reduce) and letting us know what you've tried and what's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one liner:

```js
const filtered = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(data[0]["Count"]).filter(([k]) => result.includes(k)))
```

With ES5 support:

```js
const filtered  = Object.keys(data[0]["Count"]).filter(k => result.includes(k)).reduce((acc, k) => (acc[k] = data[0]["Count"][k], acc), {})
```

Demo:

```js
let data = [{
    "Count": {
        "Grapes": 1,
        "Banana": 6,
    }
}]


let result = ["Banana"]

const filtered = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(data[0]["Count"]).filter(([k]) => result.includes(k))) 

const filteredES5  = Object.keys(data[0]["Count"]).filter(k => result.includes(k)).reduce((acc, k) => {acc[k] = data[0]["Count"][k]; return acc}, {})


console.log(filtered);
console.log(filteredES5);
```

Comment: Thanks @cthmsst...but works only with the latest ES.with es5 it wont work

Comment: Updated my example with ES5 support

Answer (score 0):

This would work for your values:

```
result.map(item => data[0].Count[item])
```

If you want key value and remove the undefined values as well:

```
result.map(item =>{return  data[0].Count[item] ? {[item] : data[0].Count[item]} : undefined} ).filter(item => item != undefined)
```

Comment: It will return `[6]` for `'Banana'` and `[ undefined ]` if item is not present in `Count`

Comment: To remove the array you could use `reduce` and to prevent creating new key when undefined you could do: `result.reduce((acc, k) => data[0].Count[k] ? (acc[k] = data[0].Count[k], acc) : acc, {})`

Comment: Yeah or you can do 

result.map(item =>{return  data[0].Count[item] ? {[item] : data[0].Count[item]} : undefined} ).filter(item => item != undefined);

to remove undefined values.

Comment: Yep, but you'll still have `[ { Banana: 6 } ]` instead of `{ Banana: 6 }`